# Can wcf be debugged for calls happening from java web service client

Tags: wcf, debugging

I am working on passing a small byte[] between a wcf method to java web service client, which was working well untill today. I have tried testing my wcf method from .net web client it works fine, only from java client it's breaking.

So i wanted to actually debug my wcf once java client app makes call to it, is anyone aware of any way by which we can get wcf into debugging once any of it's client (Non .net ones, mainly java) calls any method of it?

Just to add: I know tracing, i have enabled and tried to get to root of issue with that, but i just wanted to make looking for issue bit faster by bypassing need to look into wcf trace, as debugging seems saving some time, if posible.

Comment: This seems rather easy, restart your web service, make sure debugger is attached at server-side, then start your java client (make sure no other clients are running at this point).  "Easy" if this your development environment, that is.

Comment: @ Chris : Thanks for input.I had already tried this but didn't work, so only asked if to debug wcf for non .net clients need different approach. but finally i came to know this same approach works fine, only thing was i did a stupid mistake. my wcf was hosted in IIS, but while trying to debug in VS2010, i was having wcf running in casini server (it was done long back,not pointed to virtual directory url where it was hosted in IIS), hence i was not able to get wcf into debug for client's calls, as client was referring to service hosted at IIS. a great learning indeed for what can go silly.